# Virtual host alias not working as expected?

Tags: regex, apache, laravel, .htaccess, virtualhost

I am in a situation where I need to set up multiple projects in a single folder (all of these are laravel/lumen based).

When I am using this configuration everything is working fine.

**Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost>
    ServerAdmin admin@abc.com
    ServerName dev.abc.com
    ServerAlias www.dev.abc.com
    Alias "/wigs" "/var/www/abc/v1/wigs/public"
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc

    <Directory /var/www/abc>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Htaccess in public folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # api setting
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (wigs)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wigs/$1 [L]    
</IfModule>
```

But I need to add a v1 in the Alias before wigs like this "v1/wigs"

Then the error Apache2 is throwing back is

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

I tried adjusting the RegEx in the htaccess file but it's not working.
I am not very good at RegEx.

Comment: are you also adding v1 in the RewriteRule section of your .htaccess?

Comment: @WillBarnwell Yeah I added it like this but it was still not working     # api setting
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} v1/(wigs)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v1/wigs/$1 [L]

Comment: It's weird but I figured it out that the v1 as url and v1 as the directory name shouldn't be same.

Comment: Congrats, I recommend self answer your question and explain what you think was happening in that answer so that the next person facing such an issue doesn't need to struggle (plus you'll get sweet internet points)